# R: group XY point cluster, convert to density & save

Tags: r, spatial, plyr, apply, density-plot

**Goal**: change a set of point clusters into a density distribution.

**Specifics**: point clusters are well separated, and I'm interested in the density values of each sampling site (by count).I've been converting the counts by hand and an algorithm to allocate points into densities would be invaluable.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this and am very open to creative input!

Here's what the entire dataset looks like:

```
> head(markers)
          x        y
1 -494.5768 300.6698
2 -494.4280 300.7582
3 -494.5812 300.8424
4 -494.4000 300.9146
5 -494.8554 300.9102
6 -494.8038 300.9974
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ewcggnp3p29vhjh/datapoints.csv

I'd like to get an output in this format

```
     x  y density
1    6  1     0.0
2    7  1    17.6
3    8  1    11.2
4   12  1    14.4
5   13  1     0.0
6   14  1     8.0
7   14  2     0.0
```

etc

the x y points would be much larger, like -494.5768

I think it'd have to do something along the lines of ...

1. calculate distances between all point combinations
2. group the rows that have distances under a set threshold
3. subset/split clusters with plyr
4. find the average XY coordinates of the cluster
5. assign length(cluster) to the XY point.
6. recombine all the rows

Comment: What are your desired `x` and `y`? I guess you want the predicted density on a grid of values. Any preferences on how dense/sparse the grid should be?

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with plyr that I can see.

Comment: @HongOoi Hi- the xy output should be the mean coordinate of all of the cluster's points. it would probably look like (x=-494.5768, y=300.6698) and a 'Z' integer value of the count; this example would have a total of ~200 rows. A threshold value should be involved to tailor how close points must be to be grouped. plot(datapoints) shows how the data looks (it always looks like that). Thanks again!